# Logstash Exception: Errno::EACCES in reading csv file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I trying am reading a csv file and index it into elastic.
Logstash is giving this error:

> [2020-03-15T14:43:02,424][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
>     Pipeline_id:main
>     Plugin: "beginning", path=>["/Users/shivam/Documents/logstash_example/cars.csv"], id=>"csv_elastic", sincedb_path=>"/dev/null", enable_metric=>true, codec=>"plain_c8e06e64-c1d8-49ea-aa2f-e54c38c96929", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, stat_interval=>1.0, discover_interval=>15, sincedb_write_interval=>15.0, delimiter=>"\n", close_older=>3600.0, mode=>"tail", file_completed_action=>"delete", sincedb_clean_after=>1209600.0, file_chunk_size=>32768, file_chunk_count=>140737488355327, file_sort_by=>"last_modified", file_sort_direction=>"asc", exit_after_read=>false>
>     Error: Permission denied - Permission denied
>     Exception: Errno::EACCES
>     Stack: org/jruby/RubyFile.java:1269:in `utime'
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/fileutils.rb:1133:in`block in touch'
>   org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1814:in `each'
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/fileutils.rb:1130:in`touch'
>   /Users/shivam/Workspace/elastic_stack/logstash-7.6.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.16/lib/filewatch/sincedb_collection.rb:22:in `initialize'
>   /Users/shivam/Workspace/elastic_stack/logstash-7.6.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.16/lib/filewatch/observing_base.rb:62:in`build_watch_and_dependencies'
>   /Users/shivam/Workspace/elastic_stack/logstash-7.6.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.16/lib/filewatch/observing_base.rb:56:in `initialize'
>   /Users/shivam/Workspace/elastic_stack/logstash-7.6.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.16/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:341:in`start_processing'
>   /Users/shivam/Workspace/elastic_stack/logstash-7.6.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.16/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:346:in `run'
>   /Users/shivam/Workspace/elastic_stack/logstash-7.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:328:in`inputworker'
>   /Users/shivam/Workspace/elastic_stack/logstash-7.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:320:in `block in start_input'

Config file is like:

```
input{
file{
    id => "csv_elastic"
    path => "/Users/shivam/Documents/logstash_example/cars.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"

}
    }
    filter {
csv{
    separator => ","
    columns => ["Id","Model","Company","Engine"]
}

    }
    output{
elasticsearch{
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "cars"
    }
    stdout{}
    }
```

file permissions for csv file:

> -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 shivam  staff   85 Mar 15 13:33 cars.csv
>
> -rw-rw-rw-@ 1 shivam  staff  347 Mar 15 13:57 logstash-cars.config

tried giving all permission in logstash/logs folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try to add "sudo"
I have met and fixed such problem by this way.